# How to align multiple columns in bootstrap 3 carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out for a while. What I want is to display my featured image to the left of the carousel and its associated text to the right. I created a mockup to show you exactly what I mean.

[image: Carousel mockup photoshop]

I can get it looking how I want on a normal macbook style display, but as I resize the browser the image doesn't seem to respect its top margin and goes up and beyond the navbar. Also the image and the call to action scale past the chevron indicators on smaller devices.

The reason I have put both elements in 12 cols is because I want them stacked on top of each other on small devices and then I'll define different css at larger breakpoints.

Any help is appreciated. My bootply is here:

http://bootply.com/98845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so in order to stack them side by side, you need to give them a span of 6 columns each or as you require but the sum must be 12.

http://bootply.com/98848

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've got it looking how I like it now. My method seemed a bit hacky but it got the job done. Essentially I just used lots of media queries to readjust the image size and top margin when the layout started to break. I also discovered along the way that Bootstrap will stack columns once they reach a certain dimension.

Answer (score 0):

try..

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">

<!----FIRST SLIDE -->
  <div class="fluid-row">
   <div class="span6">
    <!-- INSERT IMAGE HERE -->
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
   <!-- INSERT TEXT HERE -->
  </div>
<!-- END FIRST SLIDE -->
</div>
<div class="item">
<!---- START SECOND SLIDE -->
  <div class="fluid-row">
   <div class="span6">
    <!-- INSERT IMAGE HERE -->
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
   <!-- INSERT TEXT HERE -->
  </div>
<!-- END SECOND SLIDE -->

</div>
</div>
```

my only issue with the above it might drop the text div below the image div on a browser <320px wide. maybe try instead of fluid-row use 'row' instead?